# How to correctly break apart routing to components in react-router-dom v4.3.1

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am looking to break apart my routing file into components so instead of

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/recruiter" >
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            /* HOMEPAGE ROUTES */
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/how-and-why" component={Pdf} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/investor-sign-in" component={SignIn} />
            <Route exact path="/sign-in-error" component={SignInError} /> 
            /* ADMIN ROUTES */
          {this.props.AdminUser ?
            <Route exact path="/welcome" component={LandingPage} />
            <Route exact path="/companies" component={CompaniesTable} />
            <Route exact path="/:companyId/edit-success" component={EditSuccess} />
            <Route exact path="/:companyId" component={SingleCompanyTable} />
            <Route exact path="/:companyId/:formId" component={SingleCompanyEdit} /> 
            ...10+ more Admin routes
            : <Redirect to="/" />
           }
          /*USER ROUTES */
           {this.props.regularUser ? 
              ...additoinal User routes 
             : null
            }
         </Switch>
      </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

It is

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/recruiter" >
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Homepage Routes />
            <AdminRoutes adminUser={this.props.adminUser} />
            <UserRoutes regularUser={this.props.regularUser} />
             //catch all
            <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

With each Route component (such as AdminRoutes) looking like

```
export const AdminRoutes = (props) => {

  return props.adminUser ?
    <div>
       <Route exact path="/welcome" component={LandingPage} />
        <Route exact path="/companies" component={CompaniesTable} />
        <Route exact path="/:companyId/edit-success" component={EditSuccess} />
        <Route exact path="/:companyId" component={SingleCompanyTable} />
        <Route exact path="/:companyId/:formId" component={SingleCompanyEdit} /> 
        ...10+ more routes
    </div>
     : <Redirect to="/" />
```

In my understanding it should be the same render between the two options with the exception of the surrounding divs in the child component, but what happens is I can reach the routes in the first component, in this example HomepageRoutes, but none of the routes in AdminRoutes, UserRoutes etc.

I have had this previously working by wrapping sub components in switches, but then the catch all route/component (which is my 404 not found) are displayed all the time because of the contextual location change between the outer and inner switches.

I have read quite a bit on nested routes, but as far as I understand that involves wrapping the sub routes in another Route and the subroutes share the main route in their path

ie

```
const subRoute = () => {
  return (
    <Route path="/admin >
       /* this should work? */
      <Route path=/admin/:profile component={AdminProfile} />
      /*doesn't work? */
     <Route path="/add-company" component={AddCompany} />
   </Route>
)
}
```

I would like to avoid this if possible so I don't have to re-write all my routes that I'd like to 'component-ize'

Pertinent package.json info:

```
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Thank you in advance for your time and please let me know what other information to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your top-level route controller components (`HomepageRoutes`, `AdminRoutes` , etc.) in `Route` components with `path` attributes in the top-level switch.

Also note that `Switch` matches the *first* `Route` that matches a path (see [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch)), so if your first `Route` has the path `'/'` without the `exact` attribute, it will always match so you won't get to any other `Route`. To handle this, you can put your `Route` for `HomepageRoutes` at the end of the `Switch` (but before `NotFound`).

So your `BaseRouter` should look like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/recruiter" >
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/admin' render={ () => <AdminRoutes adminUser={this.props.adminUser}/> }/>
        <Route path='/users' render={ () => <UserRoutes regularUser={this.props.regularUser}/> }/>
        <Route path='/' component={ HomepageRoutes } />
         {/* catch all */}
        <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Note that any nested `Route` components need to include the *full* path. So the paths of the `Route`s nested within, say, `AdminRoutes` will need to begin with `'/admin/'`. From the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route):

> As soon as the app location matches the route’s path, your component will be rendered.

And I don't believe a `Route` or `Switch` knows whether or not it is nested.

For example if you have the location `'/admin/welcome'` but your Admin `LandingPage` only has `path='/welcome'`, the `path` and app location do not match and the `LandingPage` component will not match. Instead the `path` should be `'/admin/welcome'`.

---

Edit for updated syntax:

Instead of using the `render` (or `component`) prop on the `<Route>` component, you can pass as children, which I find to be easier syntax to read and work with.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/recruiter" >
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/admin'>
          <AdminRoutes adminUser={this.props.adminUser}/>
        </Route>

        <Route path='/users'>
          <UserRoutes regularUser={this.props.regularUser}/>
        </Route>

        <Route path='/'>
          <HomepageRoutes/>
        </Route>

        {/* catch all */}
        <Route>
          <NotFound/>
        </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, unfortunately this did not work for me. Same issue as before where I can access any of the first 'componentized' routes, in the example above all Homepage routes work, but I still cannot access any routes in the following components (Admin or User routes).

Comment: @LJ If you entered it as I had it before I can see how that would not work: I left the `path` attributes out. I've made an edit to include them.

Comment: @LJ possibly the other issue was the order of the `Route` components, so I've included handling for that in my answer.

Comment: Great, thank you, I'll try this method. Question on this, do the paths within the Admin Routes therefore all need to start with '/admin'? Or just the first wrapper route to catch the switch. Many of my paths within admin don't include that path string..

Comment: The full path needs to be included in each `Route` (not just the part after the parent's route). I'll add that to the answer for future reference.